# Run an Azure Data Factory Pipeline Continuously

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to incrementally copy data from one SQL table to another SQL table.  The watermark or key column is an Identity column.  My boss wants me to restart the load as soon as it's done...and as you know, the completion time may vary.  In Azure Data Factory, the trigger options are Scheduled, Tumbling Window and Custom Event.  Does anyone know which option would allow me to achieve this continuous running of the pipeline and how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new pipeline. Call it "run forever". Add an "until" activity with a never-true condition e.g. `@equals(1, 2)`.

Inside the until execute the pipeline which copies between tables. Ensure "wait for completion" is ticked.

If the table copy fails then "run forever" will fail and will have to be manually re-started. You likely do not want "run forever" to be scheduled as the scheduled invocations will queue should it, in fact, not fail.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline in ADF are batch-based. You can set "micro batches" of 1 min with schedule trigger or 5 mins with tumbling window.

Comment: This might be an interesting argument for letting a pipeline execute a new instance of itself. You could have an Execute Pipeline activity at the end that executes the same pipeline with "Wait on completion" unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

ADF will run in a batch. If you want to continuously load the data then you can go for Stream Analytics / Event Hub which would load real-time data